# Do companies receive notifications if an user mentions them in his/her "developer story" section?

Tags: support, developer-story, notifications, privacy

Do companies, where a user previously worked, receive *some kind of notification** if they have an employee profile on Stack Overflow and that user lists them as a previous working place?

**With "some kind of notification" I refer to something like an email, a notification like on Facebook when you are tagged on someone's post or a notification like Stack Overflow when someone mentions you on a comment*

Comment: That's 98.732% odds for "no".  But the info exchange between SO and their customers is not public knowledge.  If you've got something to hide then it is always best to not mention it.  "Disclosed upon request" is reasonable in a resume that is visible to everybody.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Companies do not receive a notification when a user adds them to their Developer Story.

This is because:

1. We haven't yet discovered a need for companies to know this.
2. There is no action for a company to take to remove it from a user's profile.

Comment: Also under GDPR there would have to permission from the user for that data to be shared with that company, or that company would have to be listed in the default privacy document where data may be shared with and explicitly what data. I would believe that's too much of a hassle for Stack Overflow with too little gain.